# how to test complex asynchronous networked code and follow tdd

Tags: java, tdd

What would be the best practices for unit testing networked asynchronous code? I am trying to do/learn tdd

I am currently planning this part of a library, but in principle:
This is a ssh client library. I want it to be asynchronous. Ssh connection process is very complex, actually. My connect method would set some connection state variables in atomic way, then use some kind of task executor to schedule a connection task. The connection requires connecting to the server, introducing by sending and receiving ssh protocol version and stuff, then completing a key exchange process, that itself is divided into few cases, because there are few key exchange algorithms each requiring different packets to be exchanged.

Although I heard that I should test public api, and test private methods by testing public methods that use it, but in this case it seems difficult, as the task is quite complex and it is probably easier to fake only parts of a negotiation versus the whole connection/negotiation, just to check each possible result of a connect method including results of every key exchange algorithm.

Is it a good justification to split the larger connect tasks into smaller ones, even though they are not publicly available to the user, and test each separate connection stage instead of just the whole connect method all at once? Does it somehow break best practices, or how to do it in a different way? For example is it testing implementation details?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the difference between Unit- and Integration-Tests. The last paragraph you wrote (testing the connection stage-by-stage) sounds like unit testing (by e.g. mocking external parts like the client, when you test the server logic), whereas the public API tests with all parts in place sounds like an end-to-end or integration test.

Comment: well the thing is that I have heard that it is good to unit test only public user facing api. I do that whenever possible, but mocking the whole negotiation in this case would be difficult, so probably better to split and unit test stages that users do not see and cannot touch. at least parts of them. Another thing is that I will also do integration testing of this code path when all necessary parts will land

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the best practices for unit testing networked asynchronous code? I am trying to do/learn tdd

The reference you need to read is [Growing Object Oriented Software](http://a.co/7ri0MQE), by Freeman and Price.  That text contains a long walk through of how to use tests to develop an asynchronous networked auction client.

The process, as described by the authors, frontloads a lot of the work to get an initial end to end test up and running first, before beginning to fill in the other details.

It's not the only way to do it, of course.

> Although I heard that I should test public api, and test private methods by testing public methods that use it

Yes, and...

> in this case it seems difficult, as the task is quite complex and it is probably easier to fake only parts of a negotiation versus the whole connection/negotiation, just to check each possible result of a connect method including results of every key exchange algorithm.

What often happens is that a complex solution can be broken down into modules, each of which contains its own "public API" --  See [On the Criteria to be Used in Decomposing Systems into Modules](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf), by Parnas.  You can then test modules individually.

It will often turn out, for instance, that your code can be organized into two piles; an internal functional core, then an imperative shell which interacts with the [boundary of your system](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries).

As a rule, the functional core is much easier to test than the imperative shell, so strive for a shell that is "so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies."

> so what is the definition of public api?

Roughly: the affordances that are accessible outside of the scope of the implementation.

Put another way, they are the parts of the module that can't be changed without rewriting the code that calls the module.

> in this case I would probably split connection process into subtasks, like connection, ssh introduction and key exchange. And test individual subtasks in isolation. Also I would test key exchange support in isolation from specific key exchange algorithm implementations. Requirements for testing each of those parts are different, and only the first requires mocking a socket.

You might also want to look at Cory Benfield's talk [Building Protocol Libraries the Right Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Evchk7aNKdQ).

> Not sure if that is okay or not.

The TDD police are not going to come kicking in your door if you don't do it "right".   At worst, they'll write you [a nasty note](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/03/19/GivingUpOnTDD.html).

Comment: okay, so what is the definition of public api? the api that is public as in uses a public keyword, or public api as in, users see it? are public methods of a package private class considered a public api? I can nicely split my connection code into smaller tasks, but most of those tasks will not be exposed to the user in any way, those are internals.

Comment: in this case I would probably split connection process into subtasks, like connection, ssh introduction and key exchange. And test individual subtasks in isolation. Also I would test key exchange support in isolation from specific key exchange algorithm implementations. Requirements for testing each of those parts are different, and only the first requires mocking a socket. Not sure if that is okay or not.